# ERD to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, erd

I am working on an assignment and am having one heck of a time getting my head wrapped around these questions. I need to be able to write in SQL Server 2014 certain select statements based solely off this ERD. I don't have any actual database to test the code off of.

I'm not asking for just the answer, because I obviously wouldn't learn anything from that.
How would I go about writing a select statement for a question like:

"Find the total number of students taught by each professor from taking lower division classes in the last 3 years, listing emp#, name, and total number of students."

My initial thought was to start a `select * from section` but I was told that using Enrolls would be better as it wouldn't require any/as many inner join's.
[image: ERD that my questions are based off of.]

Comment: From first glance, it looks like your task here is to transform the ERD/ERM into an actual relational database first, and then write the SELECT statements against the database that you designed from the ERD.
If you need a quick read with great examples of how to transform ERD into a database, check out this article: https://explainextended.com/2009/10/18/what-is-entity-relationship-model/